# .NET 6 WPF Application published as single file does not work

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-6.0, publish

I have a .NET 6 WPF application. Currently there is no dotnet publish going on, only dotnet build. In the output there are many .dll files. I'm trying to minimize file list.

I'm trying to publish via something like this:

```
dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained true --runtime win-x86 -p:PublishSingleFile=true --property WarningLevel=0
```

This is what I end up with:

[image: this is what I end up with]

If I try to run the .exe, I see the logo and then it crashes.

Event viewer info:

[image: event viewer]

No idea why it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong? I tried running dotnet publish with different parameters, but to no avail.

Also, Erecipe is a separate .exe file that gets ran in specific scenarios. Is it possible to achieve what I want in my situation?

Thanks.

Comment: The magic line in your error stack is `at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)`. Are you doing any sort of assembly scanning or reflecting to register services? There is a service that is _not_ being registered in the single file app that _is_ being registered when it's its regular DLL build.

Comment: Hello there,
So, after some debugging I commented all GetRequiredService calls that come BEFORE building the host. It works

This specific place was the culprit:
`services.AddTransient<IDrugVerificationApi>(provider =>
 provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<VerificationOptions>>().Value.UseTestVerification
  ? provider.GetRequiredService<TestDrugVerificationApi>()
  : provider.GetRequiredService<DrugVerificationApi>());`

I guess we might be doing service registration wrong. And it looks like it might have to be done differently for a single-file app.